# Detecting if object is null in Javascript - why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why I get this error from some visitors via my JS error console tracker:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

The code in question is:

```
                if (typeof item == "object") {
                    item.classList.remove('active');
                    update_specific_marker(item.getAttribute('data-what'),"remove_active_icon");
                }
```

Shouldn't this bit work:

```
if (typeof item == "object") {
```

I'm baffled as to how they get it in the first place - as I can't get any errors to come out from that page (no matter how much I play with it,  even in Chrome which is where it seems to come from)

Any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: `null` is `Object` in JavaScript

Comment: `console.log(typeof null)`

Comment: Have you tried console.log(item) before item.classList.remove('active');?

Comment: If you want to be sure it's not null do `if (item !== null)` if you want to be sure it exists and is not null do `if (typeof item !== 'undefined' && item !== null)`

Comment: You can use `Object(item) === item` to check if it is an object. This returns false for `null`, strings, numbers etc.

Comment: @adiga `item === null` suffices. In most contexts, `!item` suffices (even in this case: typically no falsy things have `.classList`).

Comment: @Amadan if OP wants to check if `item` is an object

Comment: @adiga: Ah, yeah. Sorry, did not understand that from what you wrote.

Comment: @Amadan updated comment. TBF, `Object(item) === item` returns true for functions. So, there is that.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I wasn't aware null was still considered an Object in JS. I'll rweak the code as suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `item = null`, `typeof item == "object"` is true, so inside the block you're trying to access the `classList` property of a null value. You can't do that, hence the error.

To fix it, you're going to need another condition to stop null values from accessing the code.

```
if (typeof item == "object" && item != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do `typeof null` in a JS console, it will print `object`.
so in your case if `item = null` then also `typeof item == "object"` will produce `true`

what you can do instead is

```js
if(item){
  // do things
}
```